# Does this norm inequality always hold?

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces

Let $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ be a normed vector space.
Let $x,y,z\in X$ with $\|x-y\|,\|x-z\|\leq\frac12\|x\|$.
Define $y':=\left(1+\frac{\|x-y\|}{\|y\|}\right)y$ and define $z'$ similarly.
Does $\|y'+z'\|\geq2\|x\|$ always hold?
More generally, does $\|\lambda y'+\mu z'\|\geq(\lambda+\mu)\|x\|$ always hold?

If you make drawings of the situation in $\mathbb{R}^2$ it seems like this should always hold, but I can not find any proof.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my error, sorry about that. It just led me to realize my whole approach was flawed. I thought we might be able to have $y,z$ with $||y|| = ||x-y|| = ||z|| = ||x-z|| = \frac{||x||}{2}$ with $||y+z|| < x$, which would disprove the inequality (since $y',z'$ would be $2y,2z$). Idk, it seemed plausible we can have such $y,z$ that are orthogonal or something. But now I know we can't since, $2||x|| = ||2x|| = ||y-(y-x)+z-(z-x)|| \le ||y+z||+||y-x||+||z-x|| = ||y+z||+||x||$, so $||y+z|| \ge ||x||$. So your inequality might be true...

Comment: This has wasted a lot of my time lol. May I ask how you came up with this nice question? Also, probably doesn't matter, but is vector space real?

Comment: @mathworker21 I think we need to assume $\lambda,\mu\geq0$, which means we can assume w.l.o.g. that $X$ is real. I don't remember the details, but this question came up when trying to show that a certain geometric vector space property implies completeness. For this, I tried to look at the liminf of certain balls near the elements of an arbitrary Cauchy sequence. In particular, this had to be non-empty. I ended up solving the problem by considering the liminf of a different sequence of sets, so this inequality question remains open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third time's the charm. I think it's false even when $z=x$. Let $(X,||\cdot||) = (C([0,1]),||\cdot||_\infty)$.

We have $||x||_\infty = 1, ||y||_\infty = \frac{3}{4}, ||x-y||_\infty = \frac{1}{2}$, and $||(1+\frac{1/2}{3/4})y+x||_\infty = ||\frac{5}{3}y+x||_\infty = \frac{11}{6} < 2 = 2||x||_\infty$.

[image]

Comment: Very nice! I think we can simplify the example. Let $(X,\|\cdot\|)=(\mathbb{R}^2,\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ and $x=z=(\frac12,1)$ and $y=(\frac34,\frac12)$. Then $\|x\|=1$, $\|x-y\|=\frac12$, $\|x-z\|=0$ and $y'=\frac53y=(\frac54,\frac56)$, $z'=z$, $\|y'+z'\|=\|(\frac74,\frac{11}6)\|=\frac{11}6$.

Comment: @SmileyCraft wow, $(\mathbb{R}^2,||\cdot||_\infty)$ is a thing. can't believe I didn't have that in my toolbox. thanks for the simplification (which is indeed a simplification rather than a different example).

Answer (score 2):

The inequality does always hold in a real inner product space. More generally, instead of $\|x-y\|,\|x-z\|\leq\frac12\|x\|$, we can require $\langle x,y\rangle,\langle x,z\rangle\geq\frac12\|x\|^2$.

*Lemma:*

For $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$ with $a\leq b$ and $b>0$ we have $$\frac{\sqrt{a^2+c^2}}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2}}\geq\frac{a}b.$$

*Proof of lemma:*

If $a<0$, then the left hand side is positive while the right hand side is negative.

If $a\geq0$, then $a^2\leq b^2$ and $\frac{a^2}{b^2}\leq1$, so $$\frac{a^2+c^2}{b^2+c^2}=\frac{b^2}{b^2+c^2}\cdot\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{c^2}{b^2+c^2}\cdot1\geq\frac{b^2}{b^2+c^2}\cdot\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{c^2}{b^2+c^2}\cdot\frac{a^2}{b^2}=\frac{a^2}{b^2}.$$

*Proof of statement:*

Let us assume without loss of generality that $\|x\|=1$.

Let $y=\alpha x+p$, $y'=\alpha' x+p'$, $z=\beta x+q$ and $z'=\beta' x+q'$ with $p,p',q,q'\perp x$.

Then $\|y\|=\sqrt{\alpha^2+\|p\|^2}$ and $\|x-y\|=\sqrt{(1-\alpha)^2+\|p\|^2}$.

Note that $\alpha=\langle x,y\rangle\geq\frac12$, so $\alpha>0$ and $\alpha\geq1-\alpha$.

From the lemma, it follows that $\alpha'=\left(1+\frac{\|x-y\|}{\|y\|}\right)\alpha\geq1$.

Similarly, $\beta'\geq1$.

Hence $\|y'+z'\|=\sqrt{(\alpha'+\beta')^2+\|p'+q'\|^2}\geq\alpha'+\beta'\geq2$.

More generally, $\|\lambda y'+\mu z'\|=\sqrt{(\lambda\alpha'+\mu\beta')^2+\|\lambda p'+\mu q'\|^2}\geq\lambda\alpha'+\mu\beta'\geq\lambda+\mu$.

Comment: nice, clean solution